# What does the notation $H{\parallel}ab$ mean?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, notation

In a research paper ([Phys. Rev. B 84, 052507 (2011)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.84.052507)), I have found the notation $H{\parallel} ab$, where $H$ is an applied magnetic field. In this context $a,b,c$ are the lattice vectors. What does this notation mean?

Comment: Do you understand the $H \parallel \boldsymbol{c}$ as used in the paper? Sure, they could have used $H \perp \boldsymbol{c}$ but they didn't. The crystal structure is layers along the $c$ axis, so in layer vs perpendicular to the layering makes sense.

Comment: In the first mention of "fishtail effect", the authors reference [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.80.144515) which uses the notation $H{\parallel}c$ and $H{\perp}c$. Given that this is for a right-angled crystal, $H{\parallel}ab$ can only be equivalent to $H{\perp}c$.

Answer (score 3):

The notation means H is parallel to ab.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: While this post may be unsourced speculation, it *is* an answer to the question.

Comment: Other users had issues the the uncertainty in how your framed your answer. I edited the language to be more certain. Please edit differently if I have misrepresented your answer.

Comment: Meta discussion on this answer: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13651/195139